# BigQuery Internal error when running Merge

Tags: google-bigquery

I am executing a query for merging tables. I execute this same query every week, but this time it throws me an internal error. I waited and tried it again the same day and then the next day. The error didn't go away.

Error:

```
Error running query
An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 5423415
```

My code

```
MERGE TB
        USING TBT
        ON TB.id = TBT.id
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET id = TBT.id, col1 = TBT.col1 ....
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (id, col1 ...) VALUES(id, col1 ...)
```

Do anyone know if something has changed or why is this throwing me an error now.

Update:

The third day the query worked, and a few others also. But then for another table marge (2 different tables) I got the same error.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker under the [BigQuery component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659).

Comment: I don't have support, but I will open an issue on issue tracker. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time talking to support via [BigQuery component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659), they implemented a fix in BigQuery that fixed my issue. Thread is private since I had to describe personal information and exact problem.